# Simple RDBMS for Login Mockup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a quick model to do a mock up from for a login process. I went to codeplex and the AdventureWorks stuff is way more than I need right now and I didn't really see what I was after anyway.

We are looking to prototype and business concept and I just need what I believe to be pretty standard structure. A users table, roles, etc. I just need to db part of it and was hoping there was some simple model or script out there I could throw into SQL and get started faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what programming tool you're using but asp.net has a simple membership model that is quick to install and setup (and uses the built in login/profile controls of .net)

Comment: Duh should have put a tool in there. VS2012 or Eclipse for Java stuff. Was targeting MSSQL 2008R2 for the RDBMS. I *think* I have seen the asp.net stuff before and it didn't contain the db side did it?

Comment: VS2012 will give you the login controls. You can install the tables you need using .net install stuff. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361972(v=vs.100).aspx or just search google for install aspnet_db for more info

Comment: Arrggghhh!! It generates a SQL 2012 db that of course can't be attached to SQL 2008R2.

Comment: Point it to a SQL 2008 database and it should be fine. I've done it plenty of times before